# Spoofing internet ip on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ip, spoofing

I want to spoof my internet ip on my Ubuntu 10.10 system so that I can access country specific websites. Can some one please tell me how to go about this?

Answer (score 2):

You would either need a [proxy server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server) or a [public vpn service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network).  You cannot just spoof your IP address or the internet won't work for you.

Comment: can you suggest me a good free proxy server for uk

Answer (score 0):

There's always [tor](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Tor).

Its free and there's a setup guide for vidalia (the gui client) here: https://www.torproject.org/docs/debian-vidalia.html.en

To force yourself coming out of a UK exit node, you can edit your `.torrc` file and add `ExitNodes{UK}` at the end of it. See more in the [Tor documentation](https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#ChooseEntryExit).